# Why django models changes column to INT automatically

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

This is my models file:

```
class BC_list(models.Model):
    Bc_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="BC ID")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.Bc_id)

class cdList(models.Model):
    BC = models.ForeignKey( BC_list )
    ProcessName = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="ProcessName")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.BC)+'-'+str(self.ProcessName)
```

And can anyone tell me why the BC column is a INT instead of Varchar ?
As you can see, Bc_is is a charfield.
I don't understand it,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bc_id` is not the primary key. The foreign key on `cdList` will automatically point to the actual primary key, which is probably `id` and is an integer field.

If you really want to point to a non-primary key, you can use the `to_field` attribute on the foreign key field.

(As an aside, please use descriptive model and field names.)